# checking all values if empty or filled using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to check if all values were empty using jquery.

```
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='fname'>
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='lname'>
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='nam2'>
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='nam4'>
```

I tried this but it only works on the first `input`

```
if($('.req-in')).val() == ''{
   // code here
   $(this).after('<p>empty!</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the elements and check the value:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufguwLky/)

```
$('.req-in').each(function () {
    if (!this.value) {
        $(this).after('<p>empty!</p>');
    }
});
```

---

You could also use the [`.filter()` method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cftaacfb/)

```
$('input.req-in').filter(function () {
    return !this.value;
}).after('<p>empty!</p>');
```

Comment: Why are you using this in 2nd line, then $(this) on the 3rd one? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @AmarSyla It's because `this.value` is faster than `$(this).val()`.. also, I need to use `$(this)` on the third line because `.after()` is a jQuery method. (jQuery methods can only be used on jQuery objects, thus `$()`).

Comment: Nice, this is something I didn't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) as following code:

```
$('.req-in').each(function(){
 if( $(this).val()==""){
    $(this).after('<p>empty!</p>'); 
 }
});
```